# How to construct a class in a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, console

How to construct a class in a new thread? I have a static class called Server and a non-static class called ClientHandler. I would like to run the constructor of a new ClientHandler instance in a new Thread. The constructor takes 2 arguments. I've tried multiple approaches but my process' thread count doesn't increase. A code snippet follows:

```
public static class Server
{
    //...

    public static void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        var oldserver = (Socket) iar.AsyncState;
        var client = oldserver.EndAccept(iar);
        Console.WriteLine("Client [{0}] connected from {1}.", CHandlerIndex, client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        new ClientHandler(client, CHandlerIndex); //This has to run in a new thread.

        CHandlerIndex++;
        ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnection), ServerSocket);
    }
}

public class ClientHandler
{
    private readonly Socket _client;
    private readonly Parser _pParser;
    public Security S;
    public int ClientIndex;

    //...

    public ClientHandler(Socket cSocket, int cI)
    {
        _client = cSocket;
        InitSecurity();
        _pParser = new Parser(this);
        ClientIndex = cI;
    }

    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async and Threaded are not synonymous. if you want a new thread create one explicitly using either a Threadpool,  a raw "new thread(Threadstart...)" or look at using the new task parallel library.

Comment: Why do you say Async and Threaded aren't the same? I never said they are.

Comment: This is no direct answer to my question.

Comment: Actually, it is, you have two answers both telling you to create the thread yourself. Here's a tutorial. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx. If your problem is the constructor variables, be more explicit in your question. You need t use a "ParameterizedThreadStart" and create a class to wrap your parameters (object array will do). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, classes (objects) don't run on a specific thread. Only methods do. Your request, to run a constructor on another thread looks rather pointless. It would have no effect on where/how other methods run.

In the code you have given it looks like the new  ClientHandler instance is unrooted, ie it could be Garbage collected.

Does ClientHandler have any other methods? They might be run on another thread.

Comment: I know objects don't 'run' (on a specific thread). My question was how to run the constructor of a new object in another thread. My idea was to have a thread per ClientHandler instance, for all of its methods (starting with the constructor). So yes, ClientHandler does have other methods. (Send, Receive, InitSecurity, etc.)

Comment: I think you need some method other than the ctor, that does the processing/waiting, to run on a thread.

Comment: Processing/waiting of what? The thread or the Socket's functions?